# Django - string primary key - get_absolute_url() result in no reverse match

Tags: python, django, primary-key

I want to replace the default numeric primary_key with a string.
This model was working fine with id, now I recreated it with prg and it fail in retrieving data URL.

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    prg = models.TextField(primary_key=True, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    #    return reverse('label_app.views.label_detail', args=(self.pk,))
        return reverse('label_detail', kwargs={'prg': self.prg})

lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix(self, lookup_view, _prefix, *args, **kwargs)
    495                 "a valid view function or pattern name." % {'view': lookup_view_s}
    496             )
--> 497         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
    498 
    499 

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'model_detail' not found. 'model_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern
```

this is the prg format: 'Number/number/number' from werkzeug I see:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch
>   django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'Model_detail'
>   with arguments '('180036/10/1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['(?P[\w]+)/modeldetail/$']

what am I doing wrong?
Thanks, BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex only matches alphanumeric characters, but your ID contains `/`. You should update it to be `[\w/]+`.